RAD Studio 12.2 update to Indy 10.6.3.6 causes SMTP TLS authentication to fail
I updated my Indy components in RAD Studio C++Builder as I wanted to try and add OAUTH2 to my SMTP email sending.
I saw in this thread (Add support for XOAUTH2 SASL authentication) that code had been pushed to GitHub for OAUTH2.
I downloaded the repository from https://github.com/IndySockets/ and followed the Wiki instructions to remove the existing Indy components from my RAD Studio 12.2 installation. Then I built and installed Indy 10.6.3.6.
I tried both the master branch and the sasl-oauth branch from March 2024. With both, my SMTP no longer works and gives errors for the TLS handshake.
Has something changed in the Indy initialization since the RAD Studio 12 version?
Here is my code that works with original Indy components:
try
{
    IdMessage = new TIdMessage;
    IdMessage->Encoding = meMIME;
    if (EmailBodyFormatRG->ItemIndex == 1)
    {
        IdMessage->ContentType = "text/html";
    }
    else
    {
        IdMessage->ContentType = "text/plain";
    }
    IdMessage->CharSet = "UTF-8";
    IdMessage->From->Address              = EmailSenderEdit->Text;
    IdMessage->ReplyTo->EMailAddresses    = EmailReplyToEdit->Text;
    IdMessage->Recipients->EMailAddresses = EmailAddr;
    IdMessage->Subject = Subject;
    IdMessage->Priority = mpNormal;
    IdMessage->CCList->EMailAddresses = "";
    IdMessage->ReceiptRecipient->Text = "";
    IdMessage->BccList->EMailAddresses = "";
    IdMessage->Body->AddStrings(Body);
    SMTP = new TIdSMTP;
    try
    {
        if (EmailAuthenticateCB->Checked)
        {
            SSLHandler = new TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL(SMTP);
            // SSL/TLS handshake determines the highest available SSL/TLS version dynamically
            SSLHandler->SSLOptions->SSLVersions.Clear();
            SSLHandler->SSLOptions->SSLVersions  << sslvTLSv1 << sslvTLSv1_1 << sslvTLSv1_2;
            SSLHandler->SSLOptions->Mode = sslmClient;
            SSLHandler->SSLOptions->VerifyMode.Clear();
            SSLHandler->SSLOptions->VerifyDepth = 0;

            SMTP->IOHandler = SSLHandler;
            if (EmailPortSpinEdit->Value == 587)
            {
                SMTP->UseTLS = utUseExplicitTLS;
            }
            else
            {
                SMTP->UseTLS = utUseImplicitTLS; // Port 465
            }
        }
        if ((EmailUserEdit->Text != "") || (EmailPasswordEdit->Text != ""))
        {
            SMTP->AuthType = satSASL;

            IdUserPassProvider = new TIdUserPassProvider(SMTP);
            IdUserPassProvider->Username = EmailUserEdit->Text;
            IdUserPassProvider->Password = EmailPasswordEdit->Text;

            IdSASLCRAMSHA1 = new TIdSASLCRAMSHA1(SMTP);
            IdSASLCRAMSHA1->UserPassProvider = IdUserPassProvider;
            IdSASLCRAMMD5 = new TIdSASLCRAMMD5(SMTP);
            IdSASLCRAMMD5->UserPassProvider = IdUserPassProvider;
            IdSASLSKey = new TIdSASLSKey(SMTP);
            IdSASLSKey->UserPassProvider = IdUserPassProvider;
            IdSASLOTP = new TIdSASLOTP(SMTP);
            IdSASLOTP->UserPassProvider = IdUserPassProvider;
            IdSASLAnonymous = new TIdSASLAnonymous(SMTP);
            IdSASLExternal = new TIdSASLExternal(SMTP);
            IdSASLLogin = new TIdSASLLogin(SMTP);
            IdSASLLogin->UserPassProvider = IdUserPassProvider;
            IdSASLPlain = new TIdSASLPlain(SMTP);
            IdSASLPlain->UserPassProvider = IdUserPassProvider;

            TIdSASLListEntry *se = SMTP->SASLMechanisms->Add();             se->SASL = IdSASLCRAMSHA1;
            TIdSASLListEntry *se1 = SMTP->SASLMechanisms->Add();            se1->SASL = IdSASLCRAMMD5;
            TIdSASLListEntry *se2 = SMTP->SASLMechanisms->Add();            se2->SASL = IdSASLSKey;
            TIdSASLListEntry *se3 = SMTP->SASLMechanisms->Add();            se3->SASL = IdSASLOTP;
            TIdSASLListEntry *se4 = SMTP->SASLMechanisms->Add();            se4->SASL = IdSASLAnonymous;
            TIdSASLListEntry *se5 = SMTP->SASLMechanisms->Add();            se5->SASL = IdSASLExternal;
            TIdSASLListEntry *se6 = SMTP->SASLMechanisms->Add();            se6->SASL = IdSASLLogin;
            TIdSASLListEntry *se7 = SMTP->SASLMechanisms->Add();            se7->SASL = IdSASLPlain;
            SMTP->Host           = EmailHostEdit->Text;
            SMTP->Port           = EmailPortSpinEdit->Value;
            SMTP->ConnectTimeout = 30000;
            SMTP->UseEhlo = true;
            SMTP->Connect();
            try
            {
                SMTP->Send(IdMessage);
            }
            __finally
            {
                SMTP->Disconnect();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            SMTP->AuthType = satNone;
        }
    }
    __finally
    {
        delete SMTP;
    }

The previously working SMTP now gives:
Error connecting with SSL.
error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure


"Has something changed in the Indy initialization since the RAD Studio 12 version?" - nothing that would have broken TLS handling. The more likely reason is you are probably just using the wrong OpenSSL DLLs. What  is returned by the OpenSSLVersion() function in IdSSLOpenSSL.hpp after the error occurs? Indy currently  supports up to OpenSSL 1.0.2u, which you can get from Indy's OpenSSL-Binaries repo.

Thanks for the link to the OpenSSL binaries. I downloaded them, extratcted the 1.0.2.u and made sure they are in the same folder as the exe. OpenSSLVersion returns "OpenSSL 0.9.8k 25 Mar 2009" .  Is there some setting that tells indy to look in the exe folder first, or should this be default behaviour?

My error, I have 64 bit machine, but 32 bit application, I extracted the 64bit dlls first and they obviously didn't work. Changing to the 32 bit DLLs it all works.  Thanks Remy

Glad you got it working. You should either post an answer or delete this question.

The issue was wrong OpenSSL binaries, I had fetched them directly from OpenSSL but this is not correct for Indy.

Indy currently supports up to OpenSSL 1.0.2u, which you can get from Indy's OpenSSL-Binaries repo.

Once I fetched the correct 32bit DLLs for my application, the SMTP SSL worked again. Both 32bit and 64bit are available from the Indy OpenSSL-Binaries repo.

Curious how you managed to obtain 0.9.8k DLLs "directly from OpenSSL" given that the current version is 3.4.0
